# How to add a tooltip for TableViewer cell's in Java SWT

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a `TableViewer` where each row represents different values. The string being kinda long, I would like that when I hover the mouse over the specific cell, a tooltip should pop-up with the information from the cell.

I wrote this code but tooltip is not displayed and `getToolTipText` method is never executed:

```
columnMessage.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
{
    @Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell)
    {
       // ... as now
    }

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(Object element)
    {
       return getText(element);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For `TableViewer` add a call to enable tool tips with:

```
ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(viewer);
```

where `viewer` is your table viewer.

This requires that your label provider(s) for the table are derived from `CellLabelProvider` (or one of the classes derived from that such as `ColumnLabelProvider`).

You can then override a number of methods in the label provider to control the tool tips:

```
public String getToolTipText(Object element)
```

to return the text.

```
public Image getToolTipImage(Object object)
public Color getToolTipBackgroundColor(Object object)
public Color getToolTipForegroundColor(Object object)
public Font getToolTipFont(Object object)
public int getToolTipStyle(Object object)
```

for images, colors, fonts and style

```
public Point getToolTipShift(Object object)
public int getToolTipTimeDisplayed(Object object)
public int getToolTipDisplayDelayTime(Object object)
```

to control the tool tip offset, and when it is displayed.

There are defaults for all of these so `getToolTipText` is the only one you really need to override.

So for your code you might do:

```
columnMessage.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
            ... as now
        }

        @Override
        public String getToolTipText(Object element)
        {
           // TODO return the tool tip text for 'element'
        }

        @Override
        public String getText(Object element)
        {
          // TODO get text from 'element'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: TableViewerColumn is not a label provider, look at your code again or show it to us. You should have a `setLabelProvider` call on the column.

Comment: I have edited my question and provided the code. Can you please check.

Comment: I have edited my question and provided the updated code.I am still not available to get the text from the coloumn.

Comment: Have you called ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor

Comment: Yes i have called ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor  but still it is not working for me. Please guide.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what to suggest. The code I outlined definitely works.

Comment: when I hover the mouse over the specific cell i am getting the hashcode of the element

Comment: That is the default `getText` method in the label provider - if you are going to use `getText` you need to override it and return the value you want.

Comment: can you please provide me an example.

Comment: I can't give you that because I don't know what your objects are. 'element' is your model object, so cast it to the appropriate class and get your information from it.

Comment: Hi Greg,  Following your solution i am able to get the tool-tip for my table cells.. Thank you :)

Comment: This does not seem to work if the columns have their individual column label providers which are set to the table viewer columns directly. Very odd.