# Enable tooltip for properties view table entries

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, tooltip, eclipse-rcp

I have the default PropertySheet and it works well, but I would like to add a tooltip for each cell.

Has I just want to add the tooltip, I don't think I would need to override a lot of stuff. Just extend the actual view, get the TableViewer and apply the tooltip.

So I created a new class:

```
public class RunnerPropertyView extends PropertySheet {

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        super.createPartControl(parent);
        //TODO: get the existing TableViewer
        // apply the tooltip

    }

}
```

To apply the tooltip, I think I can follow [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29646868/1204249).

My question is how can I get the existing TableViewer from the `parent` object or from the PropertySheet itself (`this`).

Is it that possible? In my understanding it should be. The TableViewer instance must be there somewhere. Just have to know the methods and/or casts to do...

Comment: `PropertySheet` is a `PageBookView` which just holds pages, there is a separate `PropertySheetPage` for each part showing properties. It is the page which hold the Tree viewer (not table). The tree viewer is `PropertySheetViewer` which only has package visibility so is pretty much impossible to change.

Comment: @greg-449 Unless you use reflection ;-)

Comment: @AryeShemesh Can you give me a simple example on how to do that? Not sure if I know how to do that in this case...

Comment: @amp something like: `Field f = PropertySheetViewer class.getDeclaredField("viewer");
   f.setAccessible(true);
   viewer = (PropertySheetViewer) f.get(<property sheet object instance>);
   f.setAccessible(false);`