# Adding tooltip for TableViewer Cells doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29646868/2013672) explains how to set tooltips for a table viewer cell. I tried to follow that but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
TableViewer coTableViewer = createBasicTableViewer(coDetailsComposite);
TableViewerColumn labelColumn = new TableViewerColumn(coTableViewer, SWT.NONE);
coTableViewer.getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

labelColumn.getColumn().setText("Property");
ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(coTableViewer);

EditingSupport coTableEditingSupport = new CoTableEditingSupport(coTableViewer, treeViewer, this, valueColumn.getViewer(), outlineElements);
valueColumn.setEditingSupport(coTableEditingSupport);

coTableViewer.setContentProvider(new CoTableContentProvider());
// coTableViewer.setLabelProvider(new CoTableLabelProvider());
labelColumn.setLabelProvider(new CoTableLabelProvider(0));
valueColumn.setLabelProvider(new CoTableLabelProvider(1));
```

As you can see I have set a label provider to the two TableViewerColumn instances. The label provider is derived from `ColumnLabelProvider` and overrides `getColumnText`. This part works. But the `getToolTipText` method is never called. What am I missing here?

```
public final class CoTableLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider implements ITableLabelProvider {

    private int columnIndex;
    public CoTableLabelProvider(int columnIndex) {
        super();
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
    }

    public Image getColumnImage(Object element, int columnIndex) {
        return null;
    }

    public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    // this method works
    public String getText(Object element) {
        if (element instanceof ...) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                ...
            } else if (columnIndex == 1) {
                ...
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(Object element) {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't mix column label providers and table label providers that causes confusion. Just use column label providers.

Comment: Okay. I removed the LabelProvider for the TableViewer and added the LabelProvider to both TableViewerColumn. `getToolTipText` is still not called.

Comment: Show us a proper [mcve] that we can test. But you should be calling `super.update` in the `update` override (or not doing the override at all).

Comment: I updated my answer and also posted the new LabelProvider.

Comment: ok, now it works. After removing the LabelProvider for the TableViewer I forgot to add the line `ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(...)` again.